# loop through arrays inside an object with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an object that contains 3 arrays, like this:

```
 {
  "year": [
    "1980",
    "1970"
  ],
  "month": [
    "01",
    "01"
  ],
  "day": [
    "1",
    "1"
  ]
}
```

I want to convert it to something like this:

```
['1980-01-1','1970-01-1']
```

How can I do this using underscore js or jQuery or pure js?

Comment: With a loop? Have you tried anything? Is it safe to assume all three arrays are guaranteed to have the same number of elements?

Comment: Do you want to go through all possible combinations of years, months and days? Do the all arrays have the same length?

Comment: No I want to produce a string from the first item in each array, second ones, and so on. and yes, the lengths are the same.

Comment: This isn't that tough of a problem. You should really try for yourself. Just iterate the first array, and use the same index to access members of the others.

Comment: Then just use a for loop.

Comment: `for(var i =0; i < in['year'].length; i++)` should do as a loop, then just add upp the components you need, `in['year'][i] + ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over your object and fill your array with `push`

```
for(var i = 0; i < object.year.length; i++){
    myArray.push(object.year[i]+"-"+object.month[i]+"-"+object.day[i])
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t4q8t7ht/

Answer (score 1):

This proposal uses [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and an array for the keys.

```js
var data = { "year": ["1980", "1970"], "month": ["01", "01"], "day": ["1", "1"] },
    result = function (data) {
        var i = 0,
            keys = ['year', 'month', 'day'],
            result = [];
        while (i < data[keys[0]].length) {
            result.push(keys.map(function (k) {
                return data[k][i];
            }).join('-'));
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the year, month, and day arrays to [`lodash#zip`](https://lodash.com/docs#zip) that will transform them to array `[[year, month, day], ...]`, and then [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that array with [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to construct an array of `['year-month-day', ...]`:

```
_.zip(myArray.year, myArray.month, myArray.day).map(function(arr) {
  return arr.join('-');
});
```

This solution does not need any additional variables and is more of [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style.

Comment: I suggest you to add some kind of explanation

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto True, updated. Also simplified.